# A Littlewood-Paley question

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

For a suitable function smooth function $\psi$ supported on  $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d: 2^{-1} \le |x| \le 2\}$, define $P_jf(x)$ as
\begin{aligned}
        P_jf(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\psi(2^{-j}\xi)\mathcal{F} f(\xi)\right)(x), 
\end{aligned}
i.e. the projection of $f$ to its frequencies localized in the range $2^{j-1}\le |\xi|\le 2^{j+1}$ by way of the forward/inverse Fourier transform. If we define
$$Sf(x) = \left( \sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} |P_jf(x)|^2 \right)^{1/2},$$
then we know we have
$$\parallel Sf\parallel_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lesssim_{d,p} \parallel f\parallel_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$
However, does the following inequality,
$$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} \parallel P_j f\parallel_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lesssim_{d,p} \parallel f\parallel_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)},$$
hold?
I'm inclined to say no.